# auto fill otp in iOS using swift and Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode8

I am new in ios application development.i try develop basic chat application . please help me to autofill otp in ios application.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code and we´ll try to help you from there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As per my experience, your OTP is generating from backend and send via SMS.

So for auto fill OTP in your field, call webservice and get the OTP string from backend and store it in one variable and than display it wherever you want.

Every time call this service when OTP receives and update the variable.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. i send otp message via sms can I able to sync that otp into my application

Comment: Welcome. If you find this answer useful than up vote it.

Comment: Thats not fair. It will hacked. Don't do that.

Comment: thank you for replying. is there any other ways to solve this problem